# jquery - how do I open a URL in a new tab/window when the user clicks on a div with no associated href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have code like this:

```
<div id='my-div'></div>
```

When a user clicks on this div, I would like to open http://google.com in a new tab or window.  I'm using jquery as follows:

```
$('#my-div').click(function() {
    // what do I put here?
});
```

Comment: window.open(strTheURL)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a new window:

```
$('#my-div').click(function() {
   window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');
});
```

or for a new tab:

```
$('#my-div').click(function() {
   window.open('http://google.com');   
});
```

Comment: Using either of these methods opens the link into a new tab and in the same window simultaneously. Any suggestions?